# Unexpected parser behaviour when adding an option (symbol: '1' | '2';)

Tags: antlr4

The grammar below matches inputs 1 and 2 but not 3:

1. ма́ма жо 1a
2. ра́ма ж 1a
3. хлеб м 1c

```
grammar Hello;

entry
  :  headword WS definition EOF
  ;

headword
  :  LETTER (LETTER | STRESS_MARK | '-')*
  ;

definition
  :  main_symbol WS index_number index_letter
  ;

main_symbol
  :  'жо'
  |  'ж'
  ;

index_number
  :  '1'
  ;

index_letter
  :  'a'
  |  'b'
  |  'c'
  |  'd'
  |  'e'
  |  'f'
  ;

WS : [ \t] ;

LETTER : [а-яА-ЯёЁ] ;
STRESS_MARK : [\u0300\u0301] ;
```

Obviously, no. 3 is not matched because 'м' is not a valid `main_symbol`. Now if I add 'м' to `main_symbol` like this:

```
main_symbol
  :  'жо'
  |  'ж'
  |  'м'
  ;
```

Test no. 3 will pass, but this also makes 1 and 2 fail. Why?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's already answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/69416290/10109396

Following parser rule created 3 anonymous lexer rule: 'жо', 'ж', and 'м'.

```
main_symbol
  :  'жо'
  |  'ж'
  |  'м'
  ;
```

They occurred before LETTER lexer rule, ANTLR4 lexer will prefer match them than match a LETTER, you can see this in `grun -tokens` output, 'м' is a 'м' token instead of a LETTER token.

```
root@antlr:~# grun Hello entry -tree -tokens
ма́ма жо 1a
line 1:11 token recognition error at: '\n'
[@0,0:0='м',<'м'>,1:0]
[@1,1:1='а',<LETTER>,1:1]
[@2,2:2='́',<STRESS_MARK>,1:2]
[@3,3:3='м',<'м'>,1:3]
[@4,4:4='а',<LETTER>,1:4]
[@5,5:5=' ',<WS>,1:5]
[@6,6:7='жо',<'жо'>,1:6]
[@7,8:8=' ',<WS>,1:8]
[@8,9:9='1',<'1'>,1:9]
[@9,10:10='a',<'a'>,1:10]
[@10,12:11='<EOF>',<EOF>,2:0]
line 1:0 extraneous input 'м' expecting LETTER
line 1:3 missing WS at 'м'
line 1:4 extraneous input 'а' expecting WS
line 1:6 mismatched input 'жо' expecting {'-', WS, LETTER, STRESS_MARK}
(entry (headword м а ́) <missing WS> (definition (main_symbol м) а (index_number жо   1) (index_letter a)) <EOF>)
```

Solution is add a parser rule as following and use it instead of LETTER lexer rule.

```
letter
  : LETTER
  |  'жо'
  |  'ж'
  |  'м'
  ;
```